# How many seats of the 14th National People’s Congress belong to the Chinese Communist Party?

Tags: china, parliament

I am doing some research, and I need to know how many seats of the 14th National People’s Congress of China (2023 - 2028) are controlled by the Chinese Communist Party. As of now, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/14th_National_People%27s_Congress) lacks this information, and I don’t know where to find it.

Hence,

- How many seats belong to the CCP in the 14th NPC?
- If this is information is not yet known, do you know when it will be?

Thank you all.

Comment: ... all of them...  "The CCP controls nomination and election processes at every level in the people's congress system"  (wiki)

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for your comment. However, your comment does not help in answering my question. If you check the Wikipedia link that I shared, or the one for the 13th NPC, you will see that there are other parties other than the CCP in the NPC. My question is not about the degree of control of the CCP. My question is, specifically, about how many seats of the 14th NPC belong to the CCP. I have now edited my question to make it clearer—apologies if it weren’t clear enough before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [full breakdown of the NPC has not been released.](https://npcobserver.com/2023/02/china-14th-npc-demographics/)

We can reasonably assume that of the 2977 delegates, about 400 are nominally "Commoners" or "Independent" leaving about 2200 for the CPC.  However as my link says, " in 2019, the NPC scrapped [information including political affiliation and age] from its website, leaving only a [barebones list.](http://www.npc.gov.cn/c2/kgfb/202302/t20230225_423685.html)"  Chinese wikipeidians have [organised this list and added further information where known](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B%E5%B1%8A%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E4%BB%A3%E8%A1%A8%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A%E4%BB%A3%E8%A1%A8%E5%90%8D%E5%8D%95)

The assumption in the list is that a delegate is Han, male and Communist (unless indicated otherwise). Deviations from this (such as women or members of other parties) can be found, but this doesn't differentiate between Communist party members and "Commoners" or "Independents". Delegates from the Communist party are not elected *as party members* in a competitive election with other parties.

In practical terms, this is not of any great significance. Even if not members of the CCP, all delegates are equally "controlled" by it.  There are no delegates who were elected against the wishes of the CCP.  And so perhaps the real answer is (as I wrote in a comment) "All of them".

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. I take it from your answer that a full breakdown by membership for the 14th NPC, like the one there is for the 13th; is unlikely to appear any time soon in Wikipedia, correct?

Comment: That appears to be correct.  Unless this information is released by the NPC, it is unlikely to appear either on en or zh Wikipedia. If it is not released by the NPC, then one would have to contact each of the nearly 3000 delegates to ask about their affiliation, which isn't a task for random wikipedians.